# JDBC, MySQL: getting bits into a BIT(M!=1) column

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm new to using JDBC + MySQL.

I have several 1/0 values which I want to stick into a database with a PreparedStatement.  The destination column is a BIT(M!=1).  I'm unclear on which of the setXXX methods to use.  I can find the references for what data comes out as easily enough, but how it goes in is eluding me.

The values effectively live as an ordered collection of booleans in the objects used by the application.  Also, I'll occasionally be importing data from flat text files with 1/0 characters.

Comment: Btw storing bits as array of boolean in java is a huge waste of memory. The concrete size of boolean depends on the runtime environment implementation and normally lies between 1-4 bytes(!). Consider using java.util.BitSet

Comment: As to your request from below. There is no sensible way the jdbc connector could understand a boolean[] without conversion as BIT(M). You will have to convert the array to something more suitable. If converting to String for my solution or to byte[] is your choice

Comment: well, it's not actually an array of booleans.  I have an ordered collection of distinguishable binary values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set a `BIT(M)` column in MySQL

For `M==1`

```
setBoolean(int parameterIndex, boolean x)
```

From the javadoc

> Sets the designated parameter to the
>   given Java boolean value. The driver
>   converts this to an SQL BIT value when
>   it sends it to the database.

---

For `M>1`

The support for `BIT(M)` where `M!=1` is problematic with JDBC as `BIT(M)` is only required with "full" SQL-92 and only few DBs support that.

Check here [Mapping SQL and Java Types: 8.3.3 BIT](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html)

The following works for me with MySQL (at least with MySQL 5.0.45, Java 1.6 and MySQL Connector/J 5.0.8)

```
...
PreparedStatement insert = con.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO bittable (bitcolumn) values (b?)"
);
insert.setString(1,"111000");
...
```

This uses the special b'110101010' syntax of MySQL to set the value for BIT columns.

Comment: My question is specifically for M!=1; I'll edit to make that more obvious.

Comment: Extended answer with solution

Comment: That works perfectly for when I'm importing my co-workers text files.  I'd still like to avoid the conversion from data to string for the non-import cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can use get/setObject with a byte array (byte[]). 8 bits are packed into each byte with the least significant bit being in the last array element.