# mysql jdbc: inserting true value to a bit column becomes false

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

mysql jdbc: inserting true value to a bit column becomes false, but
command line client works fine. For example,

Employee

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id         | varchar(8)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name       | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| full_time  | bit(1)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

command line:

```
mysql> insert into Employee (id,name,full_time) values ('100', 'John', true);

mysql> select * from Employee;
+--------+------+-----------+
| id     | name | full_time |
+--------+------+-----------+
| 100    | John |  (symbol) |      
+--------+------+-----------+

mysql> select count(*) from Employee where full_time=true;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Works.

But JDBC

```
String sql = "Insert into Employee (id,name,full_time) values (?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
s.setObject(1, "100");
s.setObject(2, "John");
s.setObject(3, true);
s.executeUpdate();
```

The row is inserted, but The full_time column is false.

```
mysql> select * from Employee;
+--------+------+-----------+
| id     | name | full_time |
+--------+------+-----------+
| 100    | John |           |      
+--------+------+-----------+


mysql> select count(*) from Employee where full_time=true;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to use setBoolean method for full_time ?

Comment: tried. not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setBoolean` to assign the true/false value to the `full_time` column:

```
String sql = "Insert into Employee (id, name, full_time) values (?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
s.setString(1, "100");
s.setString(2, "John");
s.setBoolean(3, true);
s.executeUpdate();
```

Always use the appropriate setter for the type you are trying to insert/update.  I don't know how `s.setObject(1, '100')` was even compiling, but string literals in Java use double quotes, and we should use `setString` for assigning them in a statement.

Comment: @Sunnyday My suggestion should be working for you, q.v. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601838/jdbc-mysql-getting-bits-into-a-bitm-1-column).  Are you sure that you ran my code and that there isn't another problem somewhere?

Comment: It is my own code issue. setObject(...) works too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One more option on how to set values of the BIT columns:

```java
final Blob blob = connection.createBlob();
blob.setBytes(1, bytes);
statement.setBlob(bitColumnPosition, blob);
```

This work for both `BIT(1)` and `BIT(>1)` data types.